# Drawer not navigating to next screen in React Native Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5, react-native-drawer

I am using react native drawer with navigation 5, I have created a drawer but from the drawer when I click some of option to navigate to next screen it gives me error like "Undefined is not object.. this.props" and when I define prop on top like `const navigation = this.props.navigation` it then gives me error "Navigation is undefined..."
This is my Drawer where my content is placed:

```
export function DrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <View
        style={
          styles.drawerContent
        }
      >
        <View style={styles.userInfoSection}>
          <Avatar.Image
...            
/>
        </View>
        <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
          <DrawerItem
            label="Preferences"
            onPress={() => {}}
          />
          <DrawerItem
            label="Classes"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ClassHome')} //Over Here I want to navigation
          />
        </Drawer.Section>
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

And this is where I placed my Drawer Screens:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeTimeTable from './HomeTimeTable';
import {DrawerContent} from './DrawerContent';
import ClassHome from './ClassHome';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default class DrawerScreens extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={() => <DrawerContent navigation = {this.props.navigation} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeTimeTable" component={HomeTimeTable} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="ClassHome" component={ClassHome} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `props` from `drawerContent` to your `DrawerContent` as below :

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeTimeTable from './HomeTimeTable';
import {DrawerContent} from './DrawerContent';
import ClassHome from './ClassHome';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default class DrawerScreens extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props}/>}> {/* pass props here */}
        <Drawer.Screen name="HomeTimeTable" component={HomeTimeTable} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="ClassHome" component={ClassHome} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, you can use that props directly in your custom component :

```js
export function DrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <View
        style={
          styles.drawerContent
        }
      >
        <View style={styles.userInfoSection}>
          <Avatar.Image
...            
/>
        </View>
        <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
          <DrawerItem
            label="Preferences"
            onPress={() => {}}
          />
          <DrawerItem
            label="Classes"
            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('ClassHome')} // user props here
          />
        </Drawer.Section>
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: It says props is undefined, anyway I found the solution by making my DrawerContent as a class because the props passed in it were coming from classes that's my it was giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent), the ***navigation*** prop should be passed by default to the **DrawerContent**. I would recommend doing it this way:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import HomeTimeTable from './HomeTimeTable';
    import {DrawerContent} from './DrawerContent';
    import ClassHome from './ClassHome';
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    export default class DrawerScreens extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return (
               <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={DrawerContent}>
                   <Drawer.Screen name="HomeTimeTable" component={HomeTimeTable} />
                   <Drawer.Screen name="ClassHome" component={ClassHome} />
               </Drawer.Navigator>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem lies in my DrawerContent function.

Comment: Could you provide an example repository so I could run it?

Comment: I found the solution by making my DrawerContent as a class because the props passed in it were coming from classes that's my it was giving me error. Thanks